# How to design href for restful resources in a multi region scenario with support for resource expansion

Tags: rest, restful-url

We have an API which is geographically distributed and available in multiple regions.

For example:

```
http://us-api/v1/
http://eu-api/v1/
```

Resources are replicated in all the region using cross data-center replication. How should we design the href for such resources? We also want to support resource expansion.

Should it be absolute url or it can be relative?

When POST a resource using the us-api, we can also GET the resource using the eu-api.

Thanks,
Manan

Comment: You should have one centralized API address, regardless of region. Essentially you're saying that behind the scenes your resources are all going to synchronize anyway - what's the benefit of having a geographic location in your API address? Use it for your website address - sure, but why for an API?

Comment: All application uses the endpoint in their respective region and hence we have location in the API address. How can we have 1 centralized API address for all the region and essentially isn't website address or the the domain name part of href.

Comment: I'm simply suggesting that if you are going to synchronize all the data anyway, why do you need to separate by region for your API?